# How to upload a image file to a web site through webbrowser with VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to fill website forms and I can do it with textbox, checkbox, radios, select-combobox, all by code but when I try to upload a image file I only can do it by keyboard pulsation simulation (SendKeys).

Is there any way to achieve it using only code? 
I need to know because I want that my application runs in background.

If its impossible by security reasons, can anybody show me a link with documentation explaining why?

Thank you all.

This is my working code to upload image:

```
 For Each elemento As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If elemento.GetAttribute("name") = "ad_picture_a" Then
                elemento.Focus()
                SendKeys.SendWait("                 " & Form2.Label6.Text & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: _Where's your code?_

Comment: Updated. That code works but only through sendkeys and I want to know how can I do it only with code to make my application work in background

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SetAttribute()` method to set the `value` attribute of the input-tag.

```
elemento.SetAttribute("value", "                 " & Form2.Label6.Text & "\t\t\n")
```

`\t` is the tab character, and `\n` the a new line character (assuming that you are inputting them, if you are actually trying to move the focus and click something please give me more information about that object).